# primefaces disabled component validation

Tags: validation, jsf-2, primefaces, disabled-input

I am using jsf 2.1 + primefaces 3.4.1. I've got problems with preventing validation of disabled components.

What I have is approximately this:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:dataTable id="parentDataTable" value=#{bean.list} var="parentItem"..>
        <p:column>
          ..
          <p:dataTable id="childDataTable" value=#{bean.map[parentItem]}" var="childItem">
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        some inputText
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:inputText id="inputText"
                        disabled=#{bean.selectedObjectsMap[childItem]} required="true" requiredMessage="value required" />
                    <p:message for=":form:parentDataTable:childDataTable:inputText" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Select
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkBox" value="#{bean.selectedObjectsMap[childItem]}">
                        <p:ajax update=":form:parentDataTable:childDataTable:inputText" />
                    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

The idea is that by default the inputText component is disabled and the "required value" validation doesn't work when I submit the form. When I click the selectBooleancheckbox component the inputText gets enabled and the "required value" validation works as well when I submit the form. However, when I disable the inputText back the validation continues to work and the "value required" message appears and I cannot submit the form. It seems that the JSF UI component tree on the server side doesn't properly get updated when I click on the checkbox, although visually I can see that the inputText component gets disabled every time I click on the checkbox.

Any ideas how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your validation isnt more complex than shown in this sample code, you code turn it on and off using

```
<p:inputText id="inputText" disabled="#{bean.selectedObjectsMap[childItem]}" required="#{!bean.selectedObjectsMap[childItem]}" requiredMessage="value required" />
```

Meaning you toggle required attribute with same bean value as used for disabled attribute, just add a !

Comment: One more question. Could you look at this question, please: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13740924/jsf-2-1-selectonelistbox-component-does-not-set-new-value)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to by pass validator on commandButton then you can implement

```
<f:validator validatorId="EmailValidator"  disabled="#{param['disableValidation']}" />
```

Dynamically enable and disable email validator on form.

```
<p:commandButton
                                    icon="ui-icon-remove" id="removeBtn"
                                    title="#{commonLbl.cmdRemoveCon}"
                                    disabled="#{pc_searchProspectBean.searchProspectVO.prospectVO.removeContactFlg}"
                                    styleClass="btn btn-sm btn-primary"
                                    action="#{pc_searchProspectBean.doRemoveContact(prospectTbl.indexId)}"
                                    update=":frm1:pnlProspectContact" onclick="modalDialog.show()"
                                    oncomplete="modalDialog.hide()">
                                    <f:param name="disableValidation" value="true" />
                                </p:commandButton>
```